# Angular 2 Cast JSON to Object With Read-Only Properties

Tags: json, angular

I have the following json:

```
{
    "AssetId": "Asset1",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "Rating": "BBB",
    "Dur": 0.557519237
}
```

and the class:

```
export class Constituent {

AssetId?: string;
Currency?: string;
Rating?: string;
Dur?: number;

public get maturityBucket(): string {
    const dur = this.Dur || 0;

    if (dur < 0.5) {
        return '0-6m';
    }
    if (dur < 1) {
        return '6m-1y';
    }
    if (dur < 2) {
        return '1y-2y';
    }
    if (dur < 5) {
        return '2y-5y';
    } else {
        return '5y+';
    }
}
```

}

However, when I read the JSON in like so:

```
loadConstituentData(): void {
    const url = './src/data/assets.json';

    this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.data.next(<Constituent[]>response.json());
        }, this.handleError);
}
```

The `maturityBucket` read-only property disappears.

How can I fix this?

Here is a Plunker of the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/3oRl9zIlG23jBUvUqaw6?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trying to cast an object to particular class or interface you do not change this object you just tell Typescript complier that this object has particular type for further type checking. In this case you do have all properties on your object but does not have a method (getter property which is actually the method), so doing this casting you just misleading compiler and yourself. To get this readonly property work you must add it to the object.

Yo can achieve desired behaviour by creating new instance of Constituent and assigning properties from your object. For example:

```
export class Constituent {

  AssetId?: string;
  Currency?: string;
  Rating?: string;
  Dur?: number;

  static createFromJsonObject(jsonObject: any): Constituent {
    let constituent = new Constituent();
    return Object.assign(constituent, jsonObject);
  }
  ...
}
```

and usage is:

```
this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.data.next(response.json().map(item => Constituent.createFromJsonObject(item)));
        }, this.handleError);
```

Comment: Excellent! thank you very much, this whole web stuff is taking a bit of getting use to (I'm primarily a C# developer).

Comment: Very nice response. Do you maybe want to make it just a tiny bit more readable by breaking down the operations like this.http.get(url)
.map(response.json())
.map(item => Constituent.createFromJsonObject(item))
        .subscribe(constituent => {
            this.data.next(constituent);
        }, this.handleError);
It would just help push for best practices and higher readability for new developers joining the pack.